# Sending integer or string from java server

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream

I have a java server, that can send any kind of file, but I can't manage to send a string or a integer.

Here is an example of how the file is sent.

```
File f = new File("/Users/Large/Downloads/android.jpg");
FileInputStream fis = null;
int size = (int)f.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
fis = new FileInputStream( f );
fis.read( bytes );

System.out.println("entro...");
out.write( bytes );
out.flush();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @drizzom: please post the code related to your problem with trying to send a string or integer.  We're interested in what *doesn't* work, not what works =)

Comment: The problem is that I want to make this send Srting or text, and I have no idea, could you you give me any advise or idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your call to `out.write(bytes)` with these examples that use the [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) classes.:

```java
// A string ("Hello, World").
out.write("Hello, World".getBytes());

// An integer (123).
out.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(123).array());
```

Note that at some point you will need to care about [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) to have something at the other end read these values in a reliable way.

Comment: And if I want to send a string array do you have any idea? And thanks again.

Comment: @drizzom: better to start a new question about how to write an array of strings/integers rather than try to lump it on here.

Comment: i post the question here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127227/how-to-send-a-string-array-using-sockets-and-objectoutputstream