# How to send a string array using sockets and objectoutputstream

Tags: java, sockets, objectoutputstream

I have this to send string or integer but if i want to send a string array what should i use?

```
  // A string ("Hello, World").
    out.write("Hello, World".getBytes());

    // An integer (123).
    out.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(123).array());
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I highly recommend using `.getBytes( "UTF-8" )` to get safe byte encoding for your string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write the array

```
ObjectOutputStream out = ...
String[] array = ...     
out.writeObject(array);
```

If you're using `ObjectOutputStream`, there's no need to muck about with byte arrays - the class provides high-level methods to read and write entire objects.

Similarly:

```
out.writeInt(123);
out.writeObject("Hello, World");
```

You only need to use the `write(byte[])` methods if you're using the raw, low-level `OutputStream` class.

Comment: Not to mention safe string encoding.

Comment: how can one read the same written array using `ObjectInputStream` `readObject()`?

Comment: @Kush: By casting it.  Arrays are objects.